# icu4c unicharset_extractor error Tesseract font training

Tags: fonts, tesseract, icu4c

I'm trying to train a new font using Tesseract and I'm running into issues. I searched online and could not find anything related to this issue other than those for node reinstallation. The issue I encounter has to do with not having unicharset_extractor on the path it's expected. How do I resolve this?

```
dyld[61734]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/unicharset_extractor
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      unicharset_extractor train.UbuntuBold.exp0.box
```

Comment: IMO error message is clear: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.69.dylib' (no such file)